# Como notificar pessoas de que foram convidadas a instalar um APP

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para Android mas estou com um problema. Bem, o que meu aplicativo faz:

Eu crio uma lista de músicas dentro do aplicativo e quero convidar pessoas para ouvir a lista, o que acontece é que para ouvir a pessoa tem que ter o aplicativo instalado. Mas vamos supor, se eu convido 60 pessoas, e dessas 60, 50 não tem o aplicativo, terei de avisar de alguma forma que elas foram convidadas e que se quiserem podem instalar o aplicativo. Qual a melhor forma de notificar essas pessoas? Pensei em SMS, mas 50 sms parece meio inviável. Alguém conhece alguma solução?

Preciso tornar a divulgação da lista e instalação do app o mais rápido e simples possível! Esse é o problema.

Comment: É uma opinião, então vou postar em comentário e não em resposta: não use SMS ou qualquer outra forma (mesmo em redes sociais) que seja invasiva. Isso é péssimo para a imagem do seu produto, mesmo que o produto seja fantástico e muito utilizado (vide pedidos de vida do CandyCrush no Facebook). Uma alternativa que não é invasiva é deixar a distribuição por conta do usuário. Crie um link único para a lista e indique que o usuário distribua pra quem ele deseja compartilhar (da forma que quiser). Essas pessoas podem acessar tal link e decidir por instalar seu app. É a forma do Spotify, por exemplo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O que você pode fazer, e não é tão difícil, é compartilhar o link da sua aplicação (link da playstore mesmo) com a pessoa que o usuário quer compartilhar a lista, usando um [Action Provider](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/sharing/shareaction.html) (Share Action), assim a pessoa pode escolher como compartilhar esse link (Messenger, email, whatsapp etc).

Feito isso, seria interessante você ter um [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
no seu app, configurado para capturar quando o usuário clica em algum link (é redirecionado para o navegador), como acontece quando abrimos link do YouTube, por exemplo, e o android nos pergunta se queremos abrir com o App do YouTube ou não. Assim, se nesse receiver você capturar que alguem está tentando acessar o link do seu app (se você capturar significa que o seu app está instalado) então você redireciona para o aplicativo e lá a pessoa poderá ver as notificações (supondo que seu app possua tal suporte), incluindo a de convite para ouvir a lista.

Comment: Pensei nisso, mas só tem um problema, é a heterogeneidade dos contatos. Bem, o id do usuario é o número do telefone, to usando o digits. Agora vamos supor que sejam 50 pessoas convidadas, mas o usuario nao tem crédito, só bonus, entao ele só alcançaria 35 pessoas dessas por exemplo, ou entao ele escolhe whatsapp, mas nem todo mundo tem whatsapp. Ai fica ruim alguns contatos ser de um jeito e outros de outro.

Comment: Entendi o problema. Bem, sendo assim, você tem duas opções:
Pode fazer com que o usuário escolha a forma de mandar para cada grupo de contatos, grupos que ele mesmo seleciona, supondo que ele saiba quem tem ou não whatsapp ou qualquer outra coisa. 
Ou você pode notificar por e-mail, o que, convenhamos, mesmo ainda sendo bem usado, soa como algo retrógrado se tratando de mobile. Para poder notificar por e-mail, você esbarra no problema de que todos os contatos precisariam ter o e-mail cadastrado.

Comment: De fato, a melhor saída, é deixar o usuário selecionar vários contatos, e optar por qual meio de notificação quer usar.

Comment: Pois é. O email tem esse problema também. Ta complicado, vou tentar pensar mais algo, mas por enquanto se n aparecer outra forma, o jeito vai ser pelos contatos mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara!

Comment: Ok e da nada, qualquer coisa estamos aí. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Tendo o código de usuário vinculado ao número do telefone eu usaria a seguinte estratégia.

#### 1. Cabeçalhos Usuário possuí o aplicativo

Neste caso o usuário está em sua base de dados, logo, enviaria a mensagem (push) diretamente ao aplicativo.

#### 2. Usuário não possuí o aplicativo

Neste caso o usuário não está (ainda) na base, dispararia um SMS (do seu servidor) para esse "novo" telefone, convidado para instalar o aplicativo.

---

Note que qualquer outra forma de contactar o usuário sem o aplicativo, irá depender do usuário fazer parte de uma rede social. O SMS é o único modo de contatar 99,9% dos usuários sem depender de nenhum outro aplicativo.

É obvio que também é interessante o envio por rede social, e-mail... Isso irá divulgar o aplicativo, mas o SMS é mais garantido.

Comment: Como seria esse envio de mensagens pelo servidor? Eu teria de contratar um serviço?

Comment: Sim, o envio de SMS tem um custo (quando feito por empresas que garantam o envio). Não seria bom para o produto usar o SMS do usuário para a divulgação, pois, ele arcaria com os custos do envio.